# Getting Parameter From Current URL with Angular

Tags: angularjs

How can I get parameter from the current URL ?

I have URL http://localhost/admin.brands/edit?brandid=1&brandname=samsung&isactive=1. For instance, how can I get brandid from the URL ?

I will modify this:

```
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('http://localhost/admin.brands/getJsonBrandAndEdit?brandid=XX').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.post = data;

        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you mean getting it in angular or in your server? which language. In angular you can straight away edit the string.

Comment: I want to get it in angular.

Comment: You could use angular routes, it would make your code cleaner.

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need this brandid. If you use $http.get('url') you have to put parameter in this url and this will return a result.

Comment: Use $location from angular. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be using [angular router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) or [ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (Would recommend the later one) and pass these values which are currently being passed in the query param in the route, would be much easier to read the values then from your controller.

Would have been something like this

```
.controller('PostsCtrl',
    [       '$scope','$stateParams'
    function($scope , $stateParams ) {    
        // 
        $scope.brandId= $stateParams.brandid;
        ...
```

---

Incase you dont want to do it and need a quick fix, here is something that would work...

**JavaScript:**

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var brandId = getParameterByName('brandid');
```

Source : [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: I am new at angular. Can you complete angular controller, please ?

Comment: Just use your code ( $http.get ......)  in your controller , you can access at parameter with $stateParams. Like this : $stateParams.brandid